# What are these mysterious switches on my old VCR?

Tags: consumer-electronics

I have a **Samsung VX-306/EDI** (VHS PAL) VCR bought in/from the 1990s.

I have lost the physical manual and was unable to find any digital copy of it online (what a shocker...).

Now I'm wondering what the following three switches/settings are for:

1. Located in the back on the right side: A round thing that appears to have two settings, or possibly can be "tuned" analogy between two points marked "L" and "H". It looks like it would take a small screwdriver to adjust, thus possibly not intended to be changed normally. But what does it actually do? What does "L" and "H" stand for? The non-textual "label" is simply a half-circle arrow going from the "L" (left) to the "H" (right).
2. Also located in the back on the right side: A switch which is also difficult or impossible to change with a human finger, labeled "ATT", with "ON" and "OFF" states. Hmm?
3. On the front of the VCR, inside the left hatch, there is an easily-by-human-fingers adjusted setting called "PICTURE CTL" which has three possibilities, visually marked as circles with different patterns inside, one of them being entirely filled and the others less so. For this one, I was able to find out that "CTL" probably means "Control Track Longitudinal", but even after reading a Wikipedia article, I have no clue what this actually is for!

Would you be able to assist me with my VCR mystery?

Comment: The first thing you can do is note the model name on the VCR and searching the web, which may bring up something useful (images), or lucky yet, find the manual. But at least, you shall provide photos to show the panels.

Comment: what does this have to do with engineering? ... this is a consumer product usage question at best

Comment: How about posting picture of the VCR and the switch in question?

Comment: Is the L->H screw control located next to the coaxial socket used to output an RF signal to a television?